# How can I convert List of PointF to IntPtr?

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I am working with EmguCV and I don't know how I can pass array of 2xN, Nx2, 3xN, Nx3 or 1xN (N is number of points) for image points like documented [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/215e547a-75d0-7e82-36db-bbc144cd9e22.htm).

I have a method to create an array of float[N,2] but Marshal.Copy has no overloads for multidimensional arrays and I have no idea how I can pass X and Y values as one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply call the [`cvCreateMat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/4c51e2f8-2296-af60-2ddb-10d9dfbdde95.htm) function to create these matrices. The [documentation of the native interface](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findfundamentalmat) contains good examples that show how to do this.

In order to set the data you can use [`cvSet2D`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/6c18515c-48e4-3187-62aa-5df1b748dd0a.htm). It's not as efficient as direct pointer access, but that's rather harder to achieve from managed code.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Another quick question : How should I new up MCvScalar? Its constructors have only doubles.

Comment: That is another question. Right now I don't know the answer. My guess is that you are just expected to use double and somewhere along the way something will convert to your chosen scalar type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float[,] floats = new float[2,3];
IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(floats, 0);
```

The following method might work but will have possible problems with the GC, so use it carefully:

```
float[,] floats = new float[3, 2];

fixed (void* pt = array)
{
    IntPtr intPtr = new IntPtr(pt);

    CallMethod(intPtr, other parameters...);
}
```

But the called method should somehow know what the dimensions are. Maybe by name (DoSomething2x3, DoSomething3x2, etc...), or by parameters (DoSomething(IntPtr ptr, int width, int height))

Comment: You're right. I didn't think of that. Review after edit for more feedback.

Comment: It doesn't matter how much you edit this, it's always going to be wrong. You need to create the right data structure for openCV. You can't invent your own data structure.

Comment: According to the OP, he just needed a bi-dimensional array as an IntPtr, and that is what I did here. The edit was to assure the GC won't move the array around the memory.